# Windows 8.1 won't start for specific user

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, user-accounts

Windows 8.1 loads fine till the point of welcome screen. When I login with my main user account, it takes forever loading and ends stuck at a blue screen. But when logining with another user account it loads just fine.

So, apparently there's a problem with a specific user account, not the entire windows 8.1 installation.

Is there anything I can do to fix the problem of this account?

---

### UPDATE

The system and the user account loads fine when safe mode is on; no crashes.

Comment: Log into the same user but boot to Safe Mode.  Update your question if the system crashes or not.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Since it worked with Safe Mode you will have to determine what start-up entry is causing the problem.  This means disabling each one until it works.  [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can disable the entry but not delete it.

Comment: I find it hard to use. I will give msconfig a try and disable start up programs.

Comment: msconfig alone is unlikely going to be enough.  I suggested that particular tool for a reason.

Comment: Ok. I've opened Process Explorer, and it displays a list of services, Shall I select 'kill process' (disable) for each services, and then restart my computer to see if the crash stops?